# Java convertion between hexadecimal, characters, numbers

Tags: java, hex, ascii, converters

first of all sorry for my english!! :)

i am working on trying to convert an ascii file who contains characters and numbers to a binary file!!

the problem is: if i have in my ascii file the charactere " B " in hexadecimal it will be 42  and if i have in my ascii file the number 66 in the hexadecimal it will also be 42!!

SO how can i know the difference between the value 42 in the hexadecimal does it refer to the letter B or the number 66 ???

PS: am working in JAVA.

Any help would be great appreciated!
Thx a lot

Comment: You should know what value are you reading ? If its hexadecimal then your should consider it as hexadecimal if it is decimal then consider it as decimal ! PS one of them is in hexa and other is decimal.

Answer (score 1):

> i am working on trying to convert an ascii file who contains characters and numbers to a binary file!!

There is no such thing as a *binary file*.  When people say "binary file" what they're really talking about is *any* file that you would not want to open in some text editor.  They are talking about any file *format* that is not just a representation of free-form text.  The key word there is "format".

A file format is a specification of what kind of information the file can represent (e.g., pictures, sounds, street addresses, ...) and how it is represented (i.e., how a program reads the file and decodes the information).

What does "B" mean when it appears in your ASCII file?  What does "66" mean?  How are those meanings supposed to be encoded in the 'binary' file that you want to create?  What is going to read this 'binary' file?

If you can't answer those questions, then you don't really even have a problem to work on yet.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it is an ASCII file. ASCII maps binary "things" to a character.

As you mentioned correctly HEX ASCII Code for B is 42.

HEX ASCII Code for 6 is 36. 66 would therefore result in 3636

The String B66BB would result in 4236364242. Every block of two(!) hex digits represents a single(!) character.

See this translation table: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

EDIT: ASCII doesn't know Decimals. Converting 66 (dec) to 42 (hex) is wrong. In ASCII terms 66 is twice the character 6 and not a number.